# Connect a device using ethernet port with C#

Tags: c#, ethernet

I would like to ask if it is possible to take and send raw ascii data from a logging device.

I have a device that you can connect sensors and take values (analogs and digitals).the device has got female rj45 socket which goes to an **rj45->serial** adapter, which adapter goes to **serial->usb adapter**.
I can easily control the device with ascii commands via usb(telnet terminal etc) but can I somehow remove the **serial->usb adapter**?
Can I send raw ASCII commands via my laptop's ethernet?
can I take the response of that device via my laptop's ethernet?

ps->
that's the device:
http://www.infinite.com.gr/products/202

Comment: Are you sure the device is using ethernet not some other protocol using an RJ45 connector?

Comment: i dont know.can i somehow confirm that ?

Comment: Theres a good chance it will say somewhere in the device specification.

Comment: http://www.infinite.com.gr/products/202

It mentions nothing on SPECIFICATIONS :/

Comment: @DimitrisKatikaridis the answer is no - you can't connect this device to an Ethernet port and expect it to work.  I would recommend **not** trying this.

Comment: @khargoosh i can accept that :) but can u explain it ?
How that comes since it works fine with the addition adapter to usb?

Comment: @DimitrisKatikaridis an RJ45 port is not synonymous with Ethernet.  Many devices use an RJ45 port as a UART/USART serial connector, for cost or size reasons (including cost of cables).

Comment: @khargoosh Cant i read/send raw data from UART/USART? 

Sorry for ignorance but i am really away from those stuff

Comment: The UART/USART is the subsystem within the device that is responsible for processing the raw data on the device end.  You still need to connect the other end to your controller/PC - Ethernet is not compatible.  If you have a serial port, you can use that, otherwise you need an adapter.  You are currently using a USB -> Serial adapter (which provides the UART on the controller end), you can also purchase Ethernet -> Serial adapters so you can introduce the device to an ethernet network.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.

With physical connectors there are always 2 specifications in-play: the mechanical specification (the shape of the connector), and the electrical specification (the data on the wires in the connector).

In your case, the RJ-45 (actually "8P8C Modular Connector") is mechanical specification, but the electrical specification is (I assume) RS-232 (or some other U[ART/serial-port standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter), like RS-433, RS-485, etc). RS-232 does not mandate the use of a D-Sub DB-9 connector (indeed, RS-232 often uses DB-25 instead of DB-9). While RS-232 requires 8 signal wires and 2 grounds (10 conductors in total), the *EIA/TIA 561* and *Yost* specifications define a way to combine some conductors together to allow for RS-232 to run on [8P8C connectors and Ethernet cabling](http://www.hardwarebook.info/RS-232D) (UTP Cat 5 or higher for 8 conductors).

Compare this with Ethernet (specifically IEEE 802.3u for "Fast Ethernet", typically 100BASE-TX) which is an electrical specification, which commonly uses 8P8C connectors (but not necessarily-so - and older versions of Ethernet used "vampire taps" instead - nothing like today's connectors).

Now, you might wonder if you could somehow program your Ethernet hardware so that it sends RS-232 signals down the wire instead of Ethernet frames - this is hypothetically possible if your NIC is a giant FPGA and you're also programming your own operating system - however that is unlikely, and OS-level network interfaces do not expose a way to control individual pin signals - I believe the lowest-level interface provided on Linux and Windows is a raw Ethernet frame.

A simpler solution is to get a simple cheap, solid-state 8P8C-to-DB-9 adapter :)

Comment: Serial is also not necessarily synonymous with RS-232, could be any number of other specifications e.g. RS-485 etc.

Comment: @khargoosh Thanks, I've improved my answer.